# Dynamic array in C - how to make it work?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, realloc

I'm trying to make function for dynamic arrays in C but I'm not sure, if I'm solving it right way. Could you help me?
Here is my code:

```
    int resizeArray(int array_rows, int **array[])
{   
    int new_rows = array_rows + 16;
    int *pointer;
    pointer = realloc(**array, new_rows*sizeof(int));

    if (!pointer) {
        free(**array);
        return 0;
    }

    **array = pointer;

    free(pointer);

    return new_rows; // return new rows counter

};
```

some code....

```
/* first array definition */
    int *data;
    int array_rows = 16;
    data = (int*)malloc(array_rows*sizeof(int));
```

if array is full:

```
array_rows = resizeArray(array_rows,&data);
```

Thank you very much for your reviews and tips.

EDIT:

```
int resizeArray(int array_rows, int **array){
    int new_rows = array_rows + 16;
    int *pointer;
    pointer = realloc(**array, new_rows*sizeof(*pointer));

    if (!pointer) {
        free(**array);
        return 0;
    }

    **array = pointer;

    free(pointer);

    return new_rows; // return new rows counter
}
```

some code....

```
    /* first array use */
   int *data;
   int array_rows = 16;
   data = (int*)malloc(array_rows*sizeof(*data));
```

if array is full:

```
array_rows = resizeArray(array_rows,&data);
```

EDIT - CODE WITH STRUCTURES:

```
struct MyDynamicArray {
    int maximumSize = 16;
    int length = 0;
    int* data;
}



  /* first array definition */

MyDynamicArray.data = (int*)malloc(MyDynamicArray.maximumSize*sizeof(int));


   int resizeArray(int array_rows, struct MyDynamicArray)
{   
    int new_rows = MyDynamicArray.maxSize * 2;
    int *pointer;
    pointer = realloc(MyDynamicArray.data, new_rows*sizeof(int));

    if (!pointer) {
        free(MyDynamicArray.data);
        return 0;
    }


    MyDynamicArray.maxSize = new_rows; // return new rows counter

};



 /* usage */
   resizeArray(array_rows,MyDynamicArray);
```

WORKING SOLUTION:

resizeArray function definition:

```
/**
 * resize array
 *      - its size resize X 2
 * @param max_length
 * @param data
 * @return 
 */
int resizeArray(int max_length, int **data)
{   
    data = (int *) realloc(**data, max_length * 2 * sizeof(int));
    max_length *= 2;

    return max_length; // return new rows counter

}
```

FIRST ARRAY DEFINITION

```
int *data_i;
    int max_length = 16;
    int *data;

    data = (int *) realloc((void *) data_i, max_length * sizeof(int));
```

HERE IS USAGE:

```
int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        data[i] = i;
        if(i == max_length)
        {               
            max_length = resizeArray(max_length, &data);
        }
    }
```

I hope, it's right and will help to solve someones problem.

Comment: Like this?:
int resizeArray(int array_rows, int **array){}

Comment: sizeof(int) is equal to sizeof(*pointer).. it is better because when you later change variable type you don't need to change anything in sizeof

Comment: so it should looks like edit i post?

Comment: Also you shouldn't free ing your memory immediately after you create it

Comment: So without calling free function?

Comment: Unluckily, you can't initialize your struct variables in struct definition ;(

Comment: Ok. First I will try to make working it without structures... But now it throws me **pointer being realloc'd was not allocated** and I don't know, how to solve it...

Comment: I think that this error is self-explanatory. Check if you call `alloc` before `realloc`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to located it but still nothing. Am I doint it right?:
`int max_length = 16;
    
    int *data;
    
    data = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * max_length);`

Comment: So, i hope, I solved it. I post my code at the end of my question.

Comment: Do **Not** `cast` the return of `malloc`. You just open yourself up to unnecessary errors. `data = malloc(sizeof(int) * max_length);` is fine.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Maybe even better `data = malloc(sizeof(*data) ...);`

Comment: Your FirstArrayDefinition must call `malloc` istead of `realloc`

Comment: @Quest, yep, that works fine too `data = malloc(sizeof(*data) ...);` However, when allocating struct members, I tend to show examples using `sizeof (...)` just to avoid the dereference of `*(stuct->member)` in `malloc` and the discussion of operator precedence and required parenthesis that usually follows depending on whether it is `struct member` or `struct array` being allocated `:)`

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

It very well may work, but you have pointers going crazy. The second parameter can simply be int* array (and when you call it, there is no need to reference it). This way, the call to realloc will simply take `array`, as will the calls to `free`. (and you simply have `array = pointer;`

You're freeing the newly allocated memory. This *will* cause a segfault if you try to use the array after resizing. Remove that line, memory management should be the responsibility of function.

Also, in general, dynamic arrays will resize by *doubling* their size. `realloc` is expensive, but memory these days is cheap. This noted, it may be beneficial for you to *always* call `resizeArray` whenever you write to it, and pass it the length of the array plus the amount of elements you are writing. I'm not certain what you are going to do with your new, dynamic array, but it will likely save you many headaches if you maintain something like:

```
struct MyDynamicArray {
    int maximumSize;
    int length;
    int* data;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response very much! So in your opinion it should looks like this:
`int resizeArray(int array_rows, int *array){
        int new_rows = array_rows + 16;
    int *pointer;
    pointer = realloc(**array, new_rows*sizeof(*pointer));
    
    if (!pointer) {
        free(**array);
        return 0;
    }
    
    return new_rows; // return new rows counter
}

/*  usage in code... */
array_rows = resizeArray(array_rows,&data);
`

Comment: Even better, resizeArray(struct MyDynamicArray* array, int numberOfElements) :)

Comment: Let's see: still need to double new_rows when its full, make the isFull check (or rather, isOverflowing, often you resize when it is half-full), realloc need not dereference, and neither does free, and data doesn't need the &

Comment: numberOfElements is my "array_rows" but how should looks like struct? I'm newbie in C and I've never used it before...

Comment: Thank you. So usage should be, as I posted in edit of my question?

Answer (score 0):

There are so many iterations of `MyDynamicArray` it's hard to discern the final approach taken. One area where there seems to be confusion is over **what am I reallocating?**. Here, it appears you simply have one `MyDynamicArray struct` and an `int array data` member of that struct then needs reallocating. There are a number of approaches to doing this, but a clean approach is to `#define` an initial array size, allocate your `data` array to the `initial defined size`, then when the number of elements reaches `initial size - 1` reallocate `data`.

An example taking the approach is as follows. A `typedef` to the struct has been created to cut down on typing. Look though the code, understand what it is doing where, and drop a comment if you have additional questions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRSZ 5

typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    int* data;
} MyDynamicArray;


int *resizeArray (int **mdata, size_t newsize)
{   
    int *tmp = realloc (*mdata, newsize * sizeof(int));
    if (!tmp)
        return NULL;

    *mdata = tmp;

    return *mdata;
}

int main () {

    MyDynamicArray *mda = malloc (sizeof (MyDynamicArray));
    mda->size = ARRSZ;
    mda->data = malloc (ARRSZ * sizeof (int));

    int i = 0;
    int newsize = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        if (i >= mda->size - 1)
        {
            newsize = 2 * mda->size;
            if (resizeArray (&mda->data, newsize))
                mda->size = newsize;
            else {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: reallocation failed at mda->size: %zd\n", mda->size);
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        mda->data[i] = i;
    }

    printf ("\nElements of dynamic array:\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        printf ("  mda->data[%2d] : %d\n", i, mda->data[i]);

    if (mda->data) free (mda->data);
    if (mda) free (mda);

    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** you can also assign a newpointer when you realloc if for some reason that is desirable. (e.g. `int *newptr = resizeArray (&mda->data, newsize);`) However, for simply resizing your array `resizeArray (&mda->data, newsize);` is sufficient.

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/mydynarray

Elements of dynamic array:

  mda->data[ 0] : 0
  mda->data[ 1] : 1
  mda->data[ 2] : 2
  mda->data[ 3] : 3
  mda->data[ 4] : 4
  mda->data[ 5] : 5
  mda->data[ 6] : 6
  mda->data[ 7] : 7
  mda->data[ 8] : 8
  mda->data[ 9] : 9
  mda->data[10] : 10
  mda->data[11] : 11
  mda->data[12] : 12
  mda->data[13] : 13
  mda->data[14] : 14
  mda->data[15] : 15
  mda->data[16] : 16
  mda->data[17] : 17
  mda->data[18] : 18
  mda->data[19] : 19
  mda->data[20] : 20
  mda->data[21] : 21
  mda->data[22] : 22
  mda->data[23] : 23
  mda->data[24] : 24
  mda->data[25] : 25
  mda->data[26] : 26
  mda->data[27] : 27
  mda->data[28] : 28
  mda->data[29] : 29
  mda->data[30] : 30
  mda->data[31] : 31
  mda->data[32] : 32
  mda->data[33] : 33
  mda->data[34] : 34
  mda->data[35] : 35
  mda->data[36] : 36
  mda->data[37] : 37
  mda->data[38] : 38
  mda->data[39] : 39
  mda->data[40] : 40
  mda->data[41] : 41
  mda->data[42] : 42
  mda->data[43] : 43
  mda->data[44] : 44
  mda->data[45] : 45
  mda->data[46] : 46
  mda->data[47] : 47
  mda->data[48] : 48
  mda->data[49] : 49
```